# Writing this C# function in T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, blob

This is part of the [code](https://github.com/Mirolubov/NAV_BLOB_CONVERT/blob/master/BlobToText.cs) that decompresses BLOB file (removing first 4 binary number from a `varbinary` column):

In C#:

```
Stream bStream = sqlBytes.Stream;
byte[] bytes = new byte[bStream.Length];
Encoding Rus = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");

byte[] bytesOffset = new byte[bytes.Length - 4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 4, bytesOffset, 0, bytes.Length - 4);

MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(bytesOffset);

DeflateStream decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
decompressionStream.CopyTo(outStream);

str = Rus.GetString(outStream.ToArray());
```

How could I replicate this in T-SQL (SQL Server)?

```
DECLARE @OneByte binary(1)

WHILE @current_pos <= DATALENGTH(@sqlBinary)
BEGIN  
    IF @current_pos > 4 
    BEGIN
        SET @OneByte = SUBSTRING(@sqlBinary, @current_pos, 1);

        SET @current_pos = @current_pos + 1;
    END

    RETURN CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(varbinary(max), @sqlBinary))
```

Comment: May I ask you why you want to use a language not built for these kind of things?

Comment: To be able to use this function even if I am not sysadmin. I am only dbowner so I cannot install dll.

Comment: Can you give an example? IS it correct that you would want 0x6700 to turn into 0x0700?

Comment: 0x6700 will be "g" after conversion

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `SUBSTRING` and `DECOMPRESS` to do this.

Note that `COMPRESS` and `DECOMPRESS` use GZip, you cannot change the algorithm.

```
DECLARE @str varchar(100)='hello';

DECLARE @sqlBinary varbinary(1000) = 0X12345678 + COMPRESS(@str);

SELECT CAST(DECOMPRESS(
  SUBSTRING(@sqlBinary, 5, LEN(@sqlBinary))
) AS varchar(100));
```

| **Result** |
| --- |
| hello |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9cb90adcb82a52bb0e06de35e67444e)

In your case, you can cast your column value to `varbinary(max)`

```
SELECT
  CAST(
    DECOMPRESS(
      SUBSTRING(
        CAST(YourImageColumn AS varbinary(max)),
        5,
        DATALENGTH(YourImageColumn)
      )
    ) AS varchar(max)
  )
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: I need to use this function on a "compressed" BLOB type -> image. The magic number is 0x01447C5A in my case. How should I use SUBSTRING then? The third parameter should be LEN(@sqlBinary) - second parameter right? But what will be the second parameter?

Comment: `5` because you are skipping the first 4 bytes. For `image` just cast to `varbinary(max)` first